# Prevent escaping rendered Liquid tag in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm using a manually installed version of jekyll-swfobject. It contains a Liquid Tag that renders as such:

```
def render(context)
output = super

<<-HTML.gsub /^\s+/, '' # remove whitespaces from heredocs
<div id="#{@config[:content_id]}-wrapper" style="width: #{@config[:width]}; height: #{@config[:height]}">
  <div id="#{@config[:content_id]}" style="width: 100%; height:100%">#{render_alternative_content(output)}</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // <![CDATA[
  #{render_flashvars()}
  #{render_params()}
  #{render_attributes()}
  swfobject.embedSWF(
    '#{@swf_url}',
    '#{@config[:content_id]}',
    '100%',
    '100%',
    '#{@config[:version]}',
    #{render_express_install_url()},
    flashvars,
    params,
    attributes,
    #{render_callback_function()}
  );
  // ]]>
</script>
HTML
end
```

However, the output javascript is escaped for some reason:

```
<script>
// &lt;![CDATA[
...
swfobject.embedSWF(
&#39;/url.swf&#39;,
&#39;flashcontent&#39;,
&#39;100%&#39;,
&#39;100%&#39;,
...
// ]]&gt;
</script>
```

I'm presuming I need the Jekyll/Liquid variant of Django's "mark_safe" ? But how?

Comment: looks like it's just urlencoding the content. Similar to some of these escape functions http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/ Does the browser not execute the urlencoded version?